# Yii2: how to deny access to a controller file?

Tags: rest, controller, yii2

I have `BaseController` that extends from `yii\rest\ActiveController`.
Then I have other controllers that extends from `BaseController`.
Other controllers are representing endpoints in my `REST` application, but `BaseController` is there to just hold shared functionality, and I do not want it to be used/abused by users.

How can I deny access to it, and maybe display/return some message like "Not allowed" ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply move this file and change its namespace, e.g. :

```
namespace app\components;

class BaseController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{
}
```

PS: you could also simply name it `Controller` or any other name that do not end by *Controller* (no need to change namespace then)

Comment: I have done this same thing in a project I'm working on. I wanted to reuse the shared controller in other projects, so I created a new yii2 extension `{company_name}/yii2-rest`. There, I created base classes that extend Yii's classes for `ActiveController`, `ActiveRecord`, etc. It's a little more complicated, but implements what @soju suggests in a reusable way.